# Vim: Find any line NOT ending in "WORD"

Tags: vim

In vim, how can I search for any line that does ***not*** end with (in this instance) the word "DROP"?

Answer (score 25):

```
/\(DROP\)\@<!$
```

This uses a zero-width negative look-behind assertion.  It finds *just* the line ending, and only finds line endings that don't have `DROP` immediately preceding them.

If you want to find the whole line, you can use:

```
/^.*\(DROP\)\@<!$
```

---

Note that you have to surround `DROP` with `\( .. \)` because look-ahead and look-behind assertions will only match a single "atom".  So you use the parens to group your word into a single atom.

If you tried `/DROP\@<!$`, then you'd get search results like the bold part here:

> abcdef
>   test test **DRO**
>   12345DROP
>   12345**DRO**
>   12345

---

There's a tutorial for these assertions on this page, though it doesn't use VIM regex syntax:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

You can also type this in VIM to get help on the command:

```
:help \@<!
```

Similar assertions:

```
\@=
\@<=
\@!
```

Comment: Great answer. Depending on what you want to do with those lines, `:global` might come handy: `:v/\(DROP\)$/norm ADROP` adds `DROP` to every line not ending with `DROP`.