# How to put .com at the end of email addressed by regex?

Tags: regex, vim

Example

I received a email-list from my friends but the problem is some people typed an email in full form (xxx@example.com) and some people typed (xxx@xxx without .com). And i want to improve it into the same format. How can i improve it if i want to edit them on vi?

In my emaillist.txt

```
foo@gmail
bar@hotmail.com
bas@gmail
qux@abc.com
mike@abc
john@email
```

My try:

i tried to use an easy regex like this to catch the pattern like xxx@xxx

```
:%s/\(\w*@\w*\)/\0.com/g
or
:%s/\(\w*@\w*[^.com]\)/\0.com/g
```

But the problem is this regex include xxx@example.com also

And the result become like this after i enter the command above

```
foo@gmail.com
bar@hotmail.com.com
bas@gmail.com
qux@abc.com.com
mike@abc.com
john@email.com
```

So, My expectation after substitution is should be like this:

```
foo@gmail.com
bar@hotmail.com
bas@gmail.com
qux@abc.com
mike@abc.com
john@email.com
```

How to use regex in this situation?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: What makes you think every email address should end in `.com`?

Comment: @Marcin I think there is an unfortunate precedent where "give me the regex for ____" has become acceptable.

Comment: @Marcin OK, I improved it already if have something wrong you can edit it for me especially a grammar. and if it's OK please give me an answer an up-vote for the question, Thank you.

Comment: @MikeW I know some email address don't end with .com but in my email list every email should end with .com

Comment: Wow, @terces907, I believe you shouldn't ask for upvotes, we will know if we want to upvote your question.

Comment: @LajosArpad I just don't want too many down votes because if down vote is too much i will cannot ans a question again. and i improved it because i need an answer not a reputation score.

Comment: @terces907, I think you did not understand my previous comment. Up-votes are given when the post is helpful for the reader, not when the person who created the post feels he could use one. Up-voting is a way to say "thank you", it was not created for charity.

Comment: @LajosArpad I understand you. but i think down vote at the first time it's because my question was too rough no detail then when i improve my question i just hope that it will turn from - to 0. and when it increase or decrease i will know that my question is ok or not if not i will improve it again just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
%s/^.*\(\.com\)\@<!$/\0\.com/g
```

The search pattern matches each line not ending with `.com` (i just copy-pasted the recipy from [Vim: Find any line NOT ending in "WORD"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327984/vim-find-any-line-not-ending-in-word)) and replaces it with itself with `.com` added.

Comment: You do not need to escape the dot in the substitution nor do you need a global flag as only one substitution will occur on a line. Vim golf: `:%s/\v^(\.com)@<!$/.com` or even shorter `:v/\.com$/s/$/.com`

Answer (score 3):

for gmail.com there is no need of further replace so do replace for  only gmail like this

```
/(.*)(?!\.com)\n/\.com/msi ( i considered as each mail in one new line. )
```

pls dont -vte mar i tried to explain